# RxJava/RxBinding - check if subscription exists

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java, rx-binding

I'm using RxBinding and creating a subscription in RecyclerView adapter in onBindViewHolder method, which reuses items. Is there any simple way to check if I already assigned subscriber to an EditText object and if so delete that subscription?

My code looks like this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.text.setText(mProvider.get(position).text);
    Subscription textSub = RxTextView.textChanges(holder.text).subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
        @Override
        public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
            ...
        }
    });
    subscriptions.add(textSub);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway to check if I already assigned subscriber to an
>   EditText object and if so delete that subscription?

you could keep it as class member. E.g.

```
Subscription textSub = Subscriptions.unsubscribed();
```

and then

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {

     holder.text.setText(mProvider.get(position).text);
     textSub.unsubscribe();
     textSub = RxTextView.textChanges(holder.text).subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
          @Override
          public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
               ...
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: On the side, is this dynamic subscription juggling efficient-wise? And thank You for this neat and clean solution.

Comment: *is this dynamic subscription juggling efficient-wise* it is. You are welcome